# How to convert XML enconding in Node

Tags: node.js, xml, encoding, utf-8, xml2js

I'm trying to parse [XML file](http://www.maxbike.cz/feed-dily.xml) in Node with [`xml2js`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2js) library.

The issue is that the file encoding is `windows-1250` instead of `utf-8`.

So when I try to get the values it contains wrong characters.
For example, instead of `ř` I get `Ĺ™`.

How can I convert the xml file or the string values to utf-8 in Node?

Comment: You've given a URL to the XML document, yet you refer to a file. Is the process that downloads the document and stores it preserving the bytes? Is there code to show ([edit]) for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [`util.TextDecoder`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_class_util_textdecoder), but you will need full ICU for this ([see details](https://nodejs.org/api/intl.html) how to check or get it).

Alternatively, you can try npm modules like [iconv-lite](https://github.com/ashtuchkin/iconv-lite/).